# How to set time along with Date picker in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I have used a datepicker but i wanted to use dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss format how can i do this ?? please provide sample code.Please help me.This code help me to do the task.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DatePickerExample extends Activity {

    private TextView Output;
    private Button changeDate;

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Output);
        changeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeDate);

        // Get current date by calender

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Show current date

        Output.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
                .append(year).append(" "));

        // Button listener to show date picker dialog

        changeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // On button click show datepicker dialog 
                showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);

            }

        });
   }


    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID:

            // open datepicker dialog. 
            // set date picker for current date 
            // add pickerListener listner to date picker
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            year  = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day   = selectedDay;

            // Show selected date 
            Output.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));

           }
        };
}
```

Is it possible to change my date format to dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss format??

Answer (score 0):

Also Append `timeStr`:

```
Time time = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
time.setToNow();
String timeStr = time.format("%k:%M:%S");
```